# how can I calculate in serializer ?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

this is my serializer:
**serializer**

```
start_at=serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

now I want do calculate in serializer, make this `end_at - start_at`
and give this value to `waite_time`
how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) for this matter:

> This is a read-only field. It gets its value by calling a method on the serializer class it is attached to. It can be used to add any sort of data to the serialized representation of your object.

You are not providing any details for your class, but this could be for example:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    start_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    end_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    # .... (any fields)
    diff = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_diff(self, obj):
        return obj.end_at - obj.start_at

    # .... (any meta etc)
```

You can also specify a custom method name in the `SerializerMethodField` otherwise the default is `get_<field_name>`.

Comment: I try this: `diff = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_diff')` and  `def get(self, obj): return 2`  but it doesn't work?

Comment: It shouldn't be `get` but `get_diff` or whatever you specify in `SerializerMethodField`.

Comment: Sadly this no longer works in the new Django Restframework 3